# Unanonymous likes and dislikes for comments

Tags: privacy, comments, anonymous

There are a number of websites where comments and contents can be liked (thumbed up / +1'd) or disliked (thumbed down / -1'd).
On the other hand, all the sites I am aware of hide the identity of the user who liked/disliked the comment.
E.g. [Youtube](https://www.quora.com/Does-YouTube-tell-you-who-liked-disliked-your-comment) or [Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130619180012AAC69S9).

Are you aware of any websites (social media sites, news sites, blogs, etc.) where the identity of the likers/dislikers are also visible either for the owner of the comment/content or for every visitor?

I know that Disqus comment plug-in makes it visible who liked the comments but it hides who disliked the comments. I am looking for sites where both likers and dislikers are visible.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Source code hosting & issue tracking service [GitHub](https://github.com/) has [thumbs up, thumbs down and a few other emojis](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/03/11/github-wants-shut-added-emoji-reactions/) registered members can add to issues and comments. If you hover over an emoji, you can see which users posted that emoji, even as an anonymous user.

It took me a while to find a [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) issue with both types, but [this one](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/issues/811) is a good example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Are you aware of any other instances?

Comment: No ... I think I would have mentioned them if I did, maybe less extensive than this example.